# Unexpected result when assigning and printing pointer value of two-dimensional array with its name

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

From my understanding of two-dimensional arrays, let's say if I declare
`int a[3][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};`, it will be stored in a memory in exact order.

And the address of each row can be written like this:
`a[0]` is equal to `&a[0][0]`, `a[1]` is equal to `&a[1][0]`, and `a[2]` is equal to `&a[2][0]`. So each `a[n]` is a `int*` type variable.

And since array name `a` is originally `&a[0]`, it will be a `int**` type variable.

From this knowledge, I assumed that writing code like this will occur error when assigning `a` to `p`, since the type is different.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[3][3] = { 72, 4, 5,
                   6, 7, 8,
                   9, 10, 11 };

    int* p;
    p = a;    //possible error, from int** to int*

    printf("*p : %d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

But somehow the result shows the value of `a[0][0]`, which is 72. What happened here? Am I understanding something wrong about two-dimensional matrix?

Comment: You have an array of *arrays*, not an array of pointers. So `a` decays to `&a[0]`. But `a[0]` is an array of three `int` values, so the type of `&a[0]` is `int (*)[3]`. Also, `a[0]` is the same as `&a[0][0]` which is a pointer to a single `int` values, and thus have the type `int *`.

Comment: As for the assignment, it's incorrect and the compiler should at least warn about it. With that said, since all values of an array are stored contiguously (i.e. they are stored in the exact way you have initialized the arrays in) that means `p` will point to the first element of the first element of `a`, which contains the `int` value `72`. That's why you get that value when you dereference `p`. To visualize it I recommend you simply draw it using pen and paper, and draw arrows (representing pointers) to cells.

Answer (score 2):

> So each `a[n]` is a `int*` type variable.

No. The type of `a[n]` is `int [3]`, which is an array of 3 `int`.

`int *` is a pointer to an `int`.

These are different things. In memory, an array of 3 `int` has bytes for 3 `int` objects, and those bytes contain the values of the `int`. In memory, an `int *` has bytes for an address, and those bytes contain the values of the address.

In an expression, `a[n]` will be automatically converted to the address of its first element except when it is the operand of `sizeof` or of unary `&`. This conversion is performed by taking the address of `a[n][0]`, and then the result will be an `int *`. But, to work with C properly, you must remember that `a[n]` is actually an array, even though this conversion is automatically performed.

> And since array name `a` is originally `&a[0]`, it will be a `int**` type variable.

No. The type of `a` is `int [3][3]`. As with `a[n]`, in an expression, it will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element except when it is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`. The result will be `&a[0]`, and the type of that will be `int (*)[3]`, which is a pointer to an array of 3 `int`.

This will **not** be further converted to `int **`. The result of the automatic conversion will be a pointer to a place in memory where there are bytes representing 3 `int`. An `int **` would point to a place in memory where there are bytes representing an address.

> `p = a;    //possible error, from int** to int*`

Since the result of the automatic conversion of `a` has type `int (*)[3]` and `p` has type `int *`, this attempts to assign an `int (*)[3]` to `int *`. This violates the constraints for simple assignment in C 2018 6.5.16.1 1, so the C implementation is required to issue a diagnostic message for it.

Then the behavior is not defined by the C standard. However, most C implementations will convert the `int (*)[3]` to `int *` and produce a pointer to the first `int` in `a`.

Answer (score 1):

> And since array name a is originally &a[0], it will be a int** type
> variable.

You are wrong. Arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are indeed converted to pointers to their first elements. But in this case the type of elements of the array is `int[3]`. So the array `a` used in expressions is converted to a pointer of the type `int ( * )[3]`.

As for this code snippet

```
int* p;
p = a;    //possible error, from int** to int*

printf("*p : %d\n", *p);
```

then values of addresses of the expressions `a`, `a[0]` and `&a[0][0]` (it is the value of the address of the extent of memory occupied by the array) are equal each other. So using the value and interpreting it as a value of the type `&a[0][0]` you will get the value of the first element `a[0][0]`.